# Unrecognised font family 'Ionicons' | react-native

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native, vector-icons

In getting Unrecognised font family 'Ionicons'  error on Ios while its working fine on android.

things i tried:
npm link react-native-vector-icons 
npm start -- --reset-cache

[error message here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QDgur.png)

Comment: try `react-native link react-native-vector-icons` instead of `npm link ...`

Comment: still same error @JoseVf

Comment: Go to `Build Phases` on your xCode project and tell me if you see the font in the `Copy Bundle Resources` section

Comment: @JoseVf facing the same issue here, and I can't see that in copy bundle resources

Comment: @Shadow I think you just have to run the `react-native link react-native-vector-icons` command. Tell me if it works.

Comment: @JoseVf But react-native uses auto-linking, right? I am using 0.60.5